# Unexpected angular.element DOM manipulation behavior in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile application by using Ionic. Ideally, I could switch and control the visibility of the different HTML sections though DOM manipulation like `angular.element().addClass` and `angular.element().removeClass`.

Here below is a demo. When we start it, the app renders the first section `#section-1`. Three seconds later, `#section-1` is hidden and the last section `#section-2` displays without problems. But when I click `refresh` in `#section-2` to reload the view, `#section-1` can't be shown as expected and we skip to the last section. It seems that the `active` class can no longer be added to the element of `#section-1`.

I've already disabled the view cache by `cache-view="false"`. I don't know where I was wrong or if it's a bug in AngularJS/Ionic.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $provide) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout) {
  var _clearScene = function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('.active')).removeClass('active');
  };

  var _enterScene = function(scene) {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#section-' + scene)).addClass('active');
  };

  var _renderScene = function(scene) {
    _clearScene();
    _enterScene(scene);
  };

  $scope.refresh = function() {
    $state.go($state.current, {}, {
      reload: true
    });
  };

  _renderScene(1);

  $timeout(function() {
    _renderScene(2);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
section {
  display: none;
}
section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="ionicApp">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="templates/main.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view id="main" cache-view="false" can-swipe-back="false">
      <ion-content padding="true" scroll="true">
        <section id="section-1">
          Loading...
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
          Main content <a ng-click="refresh()">refresh</a>
        </section>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I read some documentation about [Angular Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) including this notice:

> Do not use controllers to:
>
> Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

So I think angular overrides somehow DOM (at the end of the digest cycle) after the manual DOM manipulation inside the controller is done. Finally I changed the business logic in the controller with some variables and used `ng-class` instead to control the visibility of section. Now it works.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $provide) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout) {
  $scope.view = {
    scenes: []
  };
  $scope.view.scenes[1] = {
    active: false
  };
  $scope.view.scenes[2] = {
    active: false
  };
  
  var _clearScene = function() {
    $scope.view.scenes[1].active = false;
    $scope.view.scenes[2].active = false;
  };

  var _enterScene = function(scene) {
    $scope.view.scenes[scene].active = true;
  };

  var _renderScene = function(scene) {
    _clearScene();
    _enterScene(scene);
  };

  $scope.refresh = function() {
    $state.go($state.current, {}, {
      reload: true
    });
  };

  _renderScene(1);

  $timeout(function() {
    _renderScene(2);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
section {
  display: none;
}
section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="ionicApp">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="templates/main.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view id="main" cache-view="false" can-swipe-back="false">
      <ion-content padding="true" scroll="true">
        <section id="section-1" ng-class="{active:view.scenes[1].active}">
          Loading...
        </section>
        <section id="section-2" ng-class="{active:view.scenes[2].active}">
          Main content <a ng-click="refresh()">refresh</a>
        </section>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```